# VBScript set value at onload

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, onload, hta

I have an HTA with VBScript that has an element set to a variable, SN2:

```
<script language="VBScript">document.getElementById("ComputerName").value = SN2</script>
```

Set to print out to an HTML textbox:

```
<html><input class="inputs" type=text id="ComputerName" name=ComputerName /></html>
```

And this works well! However, I wanted to set the value to display in the textbox on `onload`

To do this, I set my VBScript function to `<body onload="myFunction()">`. And this works well, except there is another function I need to set to `body onload`

So I was wondering if there was a way to set my `document.getElementById("ComputerName").value = SN2` to onload in a different way.

I know the way in javascript, like you can set `document.getElementById("ComputerName").onload`, but that doesn't seem to be working in VBScript. Can this be done in VBScript, and if so, how? I can't use javascript for my case. I'm referring specifically to [this method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onload_dom) (although I don't need any of that iframe stuff they have in this example). For some reason this JS way doesn't translate in VBScript.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: The `onload` works only on external resources like scripts and images, and iframes. Why don't you just call that other function from `body.onload` handler?

Comment: @Jess, can you create a 'init' function which can do all the onload activities? call the init from body onload

Comment: @VinothS, so I was trying to read up on init(). Would that basically be changing the name of my Sub to init() and keeping everything in it the same? And then calling it at body onload? Or does it HAVE to be a JS function?

Comment: @Jess, I meant as we might not be able to call 2 functions in a body onload event in VBScript, you can create a sub which will do all the onload activities like calling fisrtFunction() & secondFunction(). Then this sub can be called from body onload.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still new to VBScript so the syntax is a little weird to me, but I got this working: 
Sub init()
   Call sub1
   Call sub2
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can call many functions onload:

```
<BODY onLoad="firstFunction();secondFunction() ">
```

Comment: That's Javascript, not VBScript.

Comment: I tried that method on my functions: <body onload="InputComputerName; PreloadOptions"> and that didn't work with VBScript

Comment: major browser no more support client-side vbscript. where do you try this codes?

Comment: This is WinPE, pre boot. It's got to be VBScript. The app is not opened on a browser either, it's just an HTA

Comment: OK! try this and please give your feedback: **<BODY onLoad="vbscript:fisrtFunction();vbscript:secondFunction() ">**

Comment: @Dai if the first script tag on the page is VBscript, all other event handlers on the page are default VBScript