# Input text into two different HTML input boxes at the exact same time

Tags: html, css, input, vbscript

Is there a way where a user can enter text into an HTML input box and have the same exact text appear in another input box in real time? So not using "onclick" or anything like that. I need it to be entered into the second textbox exactly while it's being typed in the first one.

I'm looking for a solution using HTML, CSS and VBScript. My script is for an application, not for use in a web browser. I can try to convert some JavaScript code but frankly, I have to use VBScript unfortunately.

---

Here is some code I tried to put together:

```
Function syncInput()
    var syncinput = document.getElementById.(".inputs").value
    syncinput.keyup = this.val
End Function
```

Here is the front end code:

```
<input onclick="InputComputerName" class="inputs" type=text id="ComputerName" name=ComputerName /><br><br>

<input class="inputs" type=text id="RegionCode" name=RegionCode onkeyup="syncInput"><br><br>
```

I've seen some JQuery code on what I'm trying to do, and then trying to convert it over to VBScript but I'm missing something.

Comment: Hey @byobob, you might get some better success with this question if you add some context: show us what you've tried and maybe explain why you *need* to use VBScript (especially since VBScript is not usually considered a web browser scripting language. I don't think this is a _bad_ question, but I do think it appears _low quality_ to the community. **Edit:** you had a pretty well formed question when you asked about [setting a value at onload with VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396210/vbscript-set-value-at-onload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never write VBScript, but I assume this will work

```
Sub RegionCode_OnKeyUp()
  ComputerName.Value = RegionCode.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, and it is by far the cleanest solution I've ever seen with respect to this kind of problem -- even against jQuery solutions!

Comment: If I had found what `this` is in VBScript it could have been even smaller :)

Comment: How do you do this using javascript?

Comment: `document.getElementById("fieldID1").onkeyup=function() { document.getElementById("fieldID2").value=this.value;}`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it without query i think like this,

```html
<input type="text" id="left" name="left" oninput="right.value = left.value; return true;" />
<input type="text" id="right" name="right" oninput="left.value = right.value; return true;" />
```